# Printing address of temporary?

Tags: c++

In the example below, `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
  public:
    int w, h;
    Rectangle() : w(7), h(0) {} // constructor definition.
    Rectangle(int x, int y) : w(x), h(y) {} // constructor definition.
};


class MyClass {
  public:
    Rectangle trec;
    MyClass() {
    }
    Rectangle getRect() {
      return trec;
    }
};

int main() {
  MyClass a = MyClass();
  cout << &a.getRect() << endl;
}
```

... I get this error when compiling with `gcc test.cpp -o test.exe`:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:32:22: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
   cout << &a.getRect() << endl;
```

I really don't get what is temporary here - `a` is instantiated when the `cout` runs, and so `a.trec` should be instantiated too and have an address, and that is exactly what `getRect()` returns? (or does a copy get created implicitly upon `return`, because the return type is defined as `Rectangle` and not `Rectangle*`?)

In any case, I'm trying to inspect code originally written like this, and where `a.trec` is `private`, and so `getRect()` is the only thing I can use from my code - any chance to print the address of `a.trec` in such a context?

Comment: A `Rectangle` is the temporary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getRect()` is defined as

```
Rectangle getRect() {
  return trec;
}
```

Even though `trec` is not a temporary `trec` is not actually what you are returning. Since you return by value you make a copy of `trec` and put it into the functions return.  That copy is a temporary and you cannot take the address of it.

If you change the code to

```
Rectangle& getRect() {
  return trec;
}
```

or

```
const Rectangle& getRect() {
  return trec;
}
```

Now we refer to the member of `a` and we can take the address of that reference.

Comment: Thanks for that, @NathanOliver - so in other words, if the lib was written like that, then there's no chance of me getting to the address of `a.trec` without changing the library code. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Correct.  There are ways to "hack" the interface to get it but I would not suggest it as it is not portable at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
Rectangle getRect() {
      return trec;
    }
```

Returns a copy of `trec`. You don't save this copy and try to take the address of a temporary, that's illegal.

You can instead return a reference(or a pointer and just don't derefence) and then print out that address:

```
Rectangle& getRect() {
      return trec;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @JameyD - you were first, but I thought the accepted answer was a bit more detailed; cheers!